# Elmer Shoop mens open tennis wimbledon

Tags: trivia, tennis

Does anyone know if footage exists of an American amateur tennis player who got into the men's open singles at Wimbledon in the 1960's and turned out to be an absolute rubbish player which caused big changes to the definition of the title "open" singles?

Comment: Calling Bud Collins...
This sounds like something you'd have to call the Wimbledon archives about. Considering the top 2 Google search result for "Elmer Shoop Wimbledon" both reference this page - I doubt much about his match(es) at Wimbledon are referenced on the web.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/218) because it is a [source/research request](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).